# Fill column with previous values in another column spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to insert a calculated column such that when `T1 = CMP 1 Stops` it should copy the `timestamp` when `T1 = CMP 1 starts'`

```
timestamp         T1             Calculated           Expected
5/1/2017 14:00          
5/1/2017 14:15          
5/1/2017 14:30  CMP 1 Starts        
5/1/2017 14:45  CMP 1 Stops     5/1/2017 14:30      5/1/2017 14:30
5/1/2017 15:00          
5/1/2017 15:15          
5/1/2017 15:30          
5/1/2017 15:45          
5/1/2017 16:00          
5/1/2017 16:15          
5/1/2017 16:30  CMP 1 Starts        
5/1/2017 16:45  CMP 1 ON        
5/1/2017 17:00  CMP 1 Stops      5/1/2017 16:45     5/1/2017 16:30
5/1/2017 17:15          
5/1/2017 17:30          
5/1/2017 17:45          
5/1/2017 18:00          
5/1/2017 18:15          
5/1/2017 18:30          
5/1/2017 18:45  CMP 1 Starts        
5/1/2017 19:00  CMP 1 ON        
5/1/2017 19:15  CMP 1 Stops       5/1/2017 19:00    5/1/2017 18:45
5/1/2017 19:30          
5/1/2017 19:45
```

Example: `Expected` column

Note: It is not necessary that it should fill the same row when T`1=CMP 1 Stops`, even it fill all `null values` with values when `T1=CMP 1 Starts` it will work for me

Answer (score 1):

The first expression you will need is:

```
If((Trim([T1])="CMP 1 Stops") or (Trim([T1])="CMP 1 Starts"),Max([timestamp]) over (PreviousPeriod([timestamp]))) as [YourNewColumn]
```

Then, if you want to limit it to the rows where [T1] = "CMP 1 Stops" just add another calculated column:

```
case when [T1] = "CMP 1 Stops" then [YourNewColumn] end as [YourFinalColumn]
```

Comment: it did not work out, still it is taking previous period timestamp, therefore it ends up taking timestamp when T1='CMP 1 ON' for T1='CMP 1 Stops'